# Anomaly in setInterval function in asynchronous functions calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Below is the snippet of the code I am preparing to build a website.

---

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
    function h(d) {
console.log("hello");
return;

};



function func(callback) {
var httpRequest; // create our XMLHttpRequest object
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // Internet Explorer old versions
    httpRequest = new
        ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // inline function to check the status      
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 &&
            httpRequest.status === 200) {
        callback(httpRequest.responseText);

        // call the callback function
    }
};
httpRequest.open("GET", '/try_ajax',true);
httpRequest.send();
}
// call the function
setInterval(func(h), 10000); // Timer is triggered here


</script>
```

---

Interestingly, though I have set the interval at 10 seconds, in my console the "hello" is appearing only once. But it should keep appearing after 10 seconds. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is wrong

```
setInterval(func(h), 10000); // Timer is triggered here
```

You are saying take whatever is returned from `func(h)` and assign it to the timeout

```
setInterval(function(){func(h);}, 10000); // Timer is triggered here
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually calling the function in your setInterval call, which is not what you want. You should only give a reference to it and put parameters as the last arguments, like this:

```
setInterval(func, 10000, h); // Timer is triggered here
```

I'd like to give a shoutout to some who pointed out that the OP wanted additional parameters with his callback, something that I completely missed in my initial answer.

Comment: and now the `callback` is undefined.

Comment: @epascarello [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) can take parameters: `setInteval(func,1000,h);` Supported in Chrome, Firefox and Opera for ages, and now even in IE10.

Comment: @some if only the original answer had that, but if OP has to support outdated browsers, they are out of luck. :)

Comment: @epascarello Yeah. And Jake, it would be nice if you at least mention in your answer who told you about the possibility of setInterval to take more parameters.

Comment: @some Done. I hope there are no ill feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Fact of the matter is - when you do

```
setInterval(func(h), 10000)
```

return value of `func(h)` is called every 10 seconds. Your `func(h)` returns void. Therefore in effect after the first call, there is nothing to call for the `setInterval` function. Therefore you see the first invokation and nothing after that!